# MPI library - problems saving values on array

Tags: c, arrays, parallel-processing, mpi, spmd

I am trying to save values on an array at a process, specifically at number 0. So, I made a condition to save these values if its rank is 0:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int rank,numprocs;
    int count[numprocs];
    int disp[numprocs];

    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &numprocs);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);

    //... whatever

    if (rank==0) {
        //whatever
        for(i=0;i<numprocs-1;i++) {
           count[i]= ...
           disp[i] = ...
        }
        //whatever
    }

    //... whatever

    MPI_Gatherv(sendbuff,size, MPI_Type, //Send from all
                recbuff, count, disp, MPI_Type, 
                0,MPI_Communicator);            //Receive on root
}
```

In fact, `count` and `disp` at process 0 are arrays where all values are 0. I do not understand this behaviour. Is it anything wrong at first loop?

**EDIT:**

The error was not on this part of this code. This code works as expected

Comment: If it is not clear, the values of these arrays are needed on `MPI_Gatherv` function and are only significant at root process (number 0 in this case)

Comment: You are declaring your count and disp arrays with an uninitialized variable for the size (numprocs). Trying moving those declarations to after your calls to MPI_COMM_SIZE AND MPI_COMM_RANK.

Comment: I have done it, but still not saving any values; it is really weird

Comment: Does your compiler support variable length arrays? Have your tried declaring the array with a constant length instead?

Comment: Yes, I have tried declaring it with a constant length. The question, for me, is why the values are not being saved at the arrays

Comment: Ok, it is solved. The problem was not on this part of the code, I am sorry

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the line:

```
for(i=0;i<numprocs-1;i++)
```

Should be:

```
for(i=0;i<numprocs;i++)
```

In the first case (above), if numprocs is 2, only index 0 of count[] and disp[] will be initialized; leaving index 1 of these arrays uninitialized.

Comment: that's right, but still not working. The problem is that there are not any items saved on these arrays